# How to submit a JSON object with headers

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I mount a list of objects and need to turn this list into a JSON, but with headers.

I'm doing it in this way:

```
public String convertToJson(List personDto) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(personDto);
    return jsonInString;
```

I do not know how to insert headers that should have some information, like: date / time, access key etc...
For information to be placed in the header!

Then I have to send a POST with Spring Boot containing this JSON object.

My JSON has to leave like this:

```
{
    "table": "person",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "PersonID": 1,
            "name": "Name o person",
            "RM": "56656565",
            "RG": "8787845-7",
        },
        {
            "PersonID": 2,
            "name": "Name o person",
            "RM": "56656565",
            "RG": "8787845-7"   
        }
    ]
}
```

My DTO class:

```
public class PersonDto {

    private Integer lNum;
    private String sName;
    private String sRg;
    private String sRm;

    public String getsRm() {
        return sRm;
    }

    public void setsRm(String sRm) {
        this.sRm = sRm;
    }

    public Integer getlNum() {
        return lNum;
    }

    public void setlNum(Integer lNum) {
        this.lNum = lNum;
    }

    public String getsName() {
        return sName;
    }

    public void setsName(String sName) {
        this.sName = sName;
    }

    public String getsRg() {
        return sRg;
    }

    public void setsRm(String sRm) {
        this.sRm= sRm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your POJO class and the Json format you want to achieve?

Comment: I do not think you embed headers on the data you sent rather on your http request object... how are you performing your http call?

Comment: I still have not done the http request, I do not know how to do it but I have to use spring boot so the header goes in the application, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jersey client for this. It integrates well with Spring

Following the is minimum stuff you need to do to hit an endpoint of an active application along with request headers

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:7777/someApp/");
        Response response = webTarget.request().header("key", "value").put(Entity.json(jsonInString), EXPECTED_POJO.class)
```

Comment: thanks for the help friend but for the requirement i have to use jackson ... forgot to mention

Comment: @lisaandrewsmarkitks How are you going to make the HTTP request then

Comment: I do not know exactly how to do it, what is the most common way using springboot and jackson?
like this?
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
I have to send a post to a web address that will consume Json